# Positioning icons horizontally, all in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an icon next to another horizontally, however with my CSS code they go below each other, please would you take a look and see if i have made an error.

CSS;

```
#social  {
top:20px;
left:30px;
height:32px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}

.facebook {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
}
.facebook:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_active.png);
}
.twitter {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
}
.twitter:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_active.png);
}
```

and my HTML is

```
<body>
<div id="social">
<div class="facebook"></div>
<div class="twitter"></div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for your help

Comment: To be expected. `<div>` are block-level elements. Starting a new div starts a new block, which would be on its own line. You'd need to make them `display: inline-block` so they don't have an implied "newline" on them.

Answer (score 5):

Have the `facebook` and `twitter` `divs` be `display:inline-block`.

CSS:

```
.icon { display: inline-block; }
```

Html:

```
<div class="facebook icon"></div>
<div class="twitter icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two good options. Take a look at these:

```
float: left;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

I suggest learning about `float`. It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Divs are a block type element by default which puts them on different lines. You'll need to specify that they should be inline.

So, you need display:inline-block; on your facebook and twitter class.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, both `display: inline-block` and `float: left` will do the trick for getting them side-by-side - however, there are some implications.

`display: inline-block` is good for keeping the elements in the "flow of content" - but the downside is that whitespace in html (e.g. new lines between divs) becomes relevant, i.e. it will be translated in your rendered page (as space characters). You can sorta fix it with negative margin on the elements - but you could also use floats instead...

`float` takes the element out of the "flow" of content, so you might need to position other things around it (for example float all your icons, not only the ones in "social" div).

On that note, `position: absolute` also takes things out of the flow - do you really need it? I would suggest wrapping all the icons in another `div` and using padding of that containing div to offset the elements.

Here are jsfiddle versions of both solutions (i only removed background-image and replaced it with color, and added size&color to the other icons):

With `dispay: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/KQyTA/

With `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/KQyTA/1/